# Get a 3d Pose from Acceleration + rotation angles

Tags: 3d, rotations, kinematics, robotics

I am trying to get a pose (x,y,z + angles x,y,z).
What is **given** (i is a discrete time t_i):

1. pos_x(i), pos_z(i), pos_z(i)
2. rot_x(i), rot_y(i), rot_z(i)
3. a_x(i), a_y(i), a_z(i)
4. a_rot_x(i), a_rot_y(i), a_rot_z(i)
5. t_i+1 - t_i (delta)

What is **needed**:

1. pos_x(i+1), pos_y(i+1), pos_z(i+1)
2. rot_x(i+1), rot_y(i+1), rot_z(i+1)

I tried integrating that, but failed.
Is there a formula for that or can You reference me somewhere.

Comment: Welcome! Can you show a little more what you did so that we can help guide you?

Comment: So, as we know from school, that a=v/t,v=s/t => s=a/t^2 (all 1d). The Displacement of two points A=(R,a)(0,0,0,1), B=(R,b),(0,0,0,1) wrt. to the Unit Frame is D(B,A)=B*A^-1 => B=D(B,A)*A. Putting together  B=accel_mat/t^2*A.
In practice this doesn't work and doesn't take the previous velocities into account.